# Entity Framework 6.12 cascade Delete ( one to many relationship)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

i have two table `parent(id p_key,name)` and `child(addresid,city, id ForeignKey)` table have one to many relationship ,

so if i am deleting any recording from parent table then all related record should be deleted from child table

i am using entity framework code first approach

Comment: Great i love it ![sarcastic] - what is Your question ?

Comment: http://www.kianryan.co.uk/2013/03/orphaned-child/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your DB `Context`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<parent>()
    .HasOptional(c => c.child)
    .WithOptionalDependent()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

Have a look at this:[`Enabling Cascade Delete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#CascadeDelete)