# How do I do Cascading deletes with entity framework 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using delete object of an entity set to delete a row from a `GridView` which works but their is sub items I want to clear out as well

```
if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
{
     GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
     Guid strId = new Guid(item.GetDataKeyValue("id").ToString());

     player _player = _dal.GetPlayerBYID(strId);

     _dal.SoccerEntities.players.DeleteObject(_player);

     _dal.SoccerEntities.SaveChanges();
     grdSoccerPlayers.DataBind();
}
```

The query  I use is the following to gather the players

```
public player GetPlayerBYID(Guid  _playerId)
{
     try
     {
         if (_playerId == Guid.Empty)
         {
              player _player = new player();
              _player.player_id = "16-56-232";
              return _player;
         }
         else
         {
              var q = SoccerEntities.players.Where(p => p.id == _playerId);

              if (q == null)
                 throw new EntityContextException(string.Format("A player could not be found {0}!", _playerId));
              else
                 return q.ToList()[0];
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          throw new EntityContextException("GetPlayerBYID failed.", ex);
     }     
}
```

But it has a higher table called team where their is a `teamId` that links both tables. I believe what I need is cascading deletes but does that work with entity framework?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework 6.12 cascade Delete ( one to many relationship)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33210831/entity-framework-6-12-cascade-delete-one-to-many-relationship)

Comment: @user2946329 not so as i was asking for version 5 their are big differences in the two versions 1

Comment: It should works fine for you too. Just try it.

Comment: please add the team entity and if you are using fluent api or data annotations please add the mapping?

Comment: no it didnt work for me but i thin cause I dont have a foreign key setup or something